# How I can go deep into a JSON data and loop thorugh an array

Tags: json, power-automate, jsonparser, power-platform

I have an external api which return the following JSON:-

```
{
  "resultSetMetaData": {
    "page": 0,
    "numPages": 2,
    "numRows": 3,
    "format": "json",
    "rowType": [
      {
        "name": "FIRST_NAME",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "LAST_NAME",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "EMAIL",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "CITY",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "ZIP",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "STATE",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "ADDRESS",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "PHONE",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      },
      {
        "name": "UID",
        "database": "PROD",
        "schema": "RIC",
        "table": "OWNER_VW",
        "type": "text",
        "scale": null,
        "precision": null,
        "nullable": true,
        "byteLength": 16777216,
        "collation": null,
        "length": 16777216
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": [
    [
      "0",
      "HoT",
      "Hot",
      "No_Email@no-email.com",
      "Miami",
      "33",
      "Florida",
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "1",
      "Richie",
      "Hot",
      "No_Email@no-email.com",
      "Miami",
      "331",
      "Florida",
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "Jeff",
      "Hot",
      "No_Email@no-email.com",
      "Miami",
      "33",
      "Florida",
      "",
      "(0",
      "4"
    ]
  ],
  "code": "090001",
  "statementStatusUrl": "/api/statements/01a4d180-0b03-2ad4-0000-f67903a02826?requestId=4d32040e-ba17-4936-a013-7dd7ab1797aa",
  "requestId": "4d32040e-ba17-4936-a013-7dd7ab1797aa",
  "sqlState": "00000",
  "statementHandle": "01a4d180-0b03-2ad4-0000-f67903a02826",
  "message": "Statement executed successfully.",
  "createdOn": 1654725152956
}
```

now i want to loop through the items inside the data[] array, so how i can do so?

Now i wrote a test Flow and i create a Parse JSON action with the above JSON as the input and as the template, then i will get these.. so i only get rowType.. so how i can loop through the data[] array inside the rowType?

[image: johnjohn123_0-1655159045919.png]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded your data into an **object** variable called `Data` and then constructed a `For each` action beneath that ...

[image: Flow]

The expression in the screenshot is simply ...

```
variables('Data')['data']
```

That will loop through your array of `data` elements.

To get each item (which in this case is an `array`) then follow this pattern.

Firstly, initialise a variable (top arrow, variable is called `Initialize Item`) that is of type **Array** ...

[image: Flow]

Then within the `For each` loop, set that variable (as shown) by using the `Current item` dynamic object.

You will get your result from there.

Result ...

[image: Result]

Comment: ok thanks i am able to get the data .. but how i can get the items inside each data element ?

Comment: Have updated my answer but this is getting into tricky territory of providing a solution for you rather than helping you on an issue.  The next steps of reading each item within the sub array are up to you now.  I hope that helps though.